# Python - How to capture gevent socket timeout exception

Tags: python, sockets, gevent

```
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_socket()
import requests
from gevent.pool import Pool
import socket

urls = ["http://www.iraniansingles.com"]


def check_urls(urls):
    pool = Pool(1)
    for url in urls:
        pool.spawn(fetch, url)
    pool.join()

def fetch(url):
    print url
    try:
        resp = requests.get(url, verify=False, timeout=5.0)
        print resp.status_code
    except socket.timeout:
        print "SocketTimeout"

check_urls(urls)
```

If I remove the first `2 lines`, my program printing `SocketTimeout`. But with monkeypatch, my program waits forever.

Can someone tell me how to capture that socket timeout exception with monkeypatch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was gevent default timeout set to `None`. So we have to set default socket timeout manually.

```
from gevent import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)
```